# equal field values in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch

My document represents an event, and contains metadata regarding the event, as well as a large payload (1mb) that is the subject of the event.  The payload is not indexed (enabled = false)

Let's say I have 10 events with regard to the same payload.

The question is - Will ES store the entire payload for each event, or will it be smarter and record only the size and hash of the payload?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer yea, it will be in _source

by default, elastic index all fields, so best practice is to restrict your mapping
as you mentioned, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html

since the payload will be on _source even if you didnt index it,
you can exclude it while making query

```
{
    "_source": ["field1", "field2", ...],
    "query": ...,
    "size": ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few useful bits about use cases like yours [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-disk-usage.html). Specifically, elastic should do some compression, though the way I understand it might not fully compress your use case into just one payload, depending on how the index is built.

> When Elasticsearch stores _source, it compresses multiple documents at once in order to improve the overall compression ratio. For
>   instance it is very common that documents share the same field names,
>   and quite common that they share some field values, especially on
>   fields that have a low cardinality or a zipfian distribution.
>
> By default documents are compressed together in the order that they
>   are added to the index. If you enabled index sorting then instead they
>   are compressed in sorted order. Sorting documents with similar
>   structure, fields, and values together should improve the compression
>   ratio.

You could probably get the largest compression if you could identify different payloads and [sort your index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html) depending on the payloads. Maybe you could hash your payloads yourself, index the hash and use index sorting with the hash as the sort.field?